# Determining whether a set is a group under matrix multiplication

Tags: group-theory

I am aware of the process of determining groups (closure, identity, inverse and associativity) and have managed previous questions such as the set of square matrices when $\det A =\pm 1$. However I am struggling with getting my head around this set/group:

Let $S\subset M_n(\mathbb{R})$, with the property that if $A\in S$, then $A^{−1}$ exists and is in $S$. Let $G$ be a set of all possible products of a finite number of elements of $S$, that is $$G=\{A_1A_2\dots A_k:A_i\in S, i=1,\dots,k\text{ for some }k\in\mathbb{N}\}$$ Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M, N\in G$. That means that both $M$ and $N$ can be written as a finite product of elements in $S$:
$$
M = S_1S_2\cdots S_m, \quad N = T_1T_2\cdots T_n\\
S_i, T_i\in S
$$
Then clearly $MN$ is the product of finitely many elements of $S$, namely
$$
MN = S_1S_2\cdots S_mT_1T_2\cdots T_n
$$
so $G$ is closed under product.

Showing that the identity matrix is an element of $G$ requires a [minor subtlety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product).

Finally, for any matrix $M\in G$, can you show that $M^{-1}\in G$?

Comment: You don't need the empty product, because $AA^{-1}\in S$.

Comment: @almagest You might think so, but how do you know that $A\in S$? We need some sort of guarantee that $G$ is non-empty, and the empty product is that guarantee.

Comment: Yes, you are right,  you need it if $S=\emptyset$. So that brings us back to the old $\mathbb{N}$ problem. Does it contain 0?

Comment: @AlbertB Depends on whethre you feel that $0\in \Bbb N$. At any rate, if you go by "all possible products of a finite number of elements", then the empty product is definitely allowed.

Comment: is the empty product possible when i=1,\dots,k. ? sorry if a stupid question.

Comment: I am impressed by your careful reading of the question. Yes, "all possible products ..." implies that we must take $\mathbb{N}$ to include 0.

Comment: and does k vary in the questions notation? because I was thinking that if k was even you could have A * A^{-1} *B * B^{-1} which would be identity. thank you for all the help so far

Comment: @AlbertB Yes, that you could do. However, there is no guarantee in the problem statement that there are any elements at all in $S$, so it's not certain that we can find any $A$ or $B$ to multiply together like that. If we knew that $S$ contained at least one element, then the empty product would be unnecessary to mention exactly because of what you wrote there.